# Shell script for adjusting image size

Tags: bash, image-manipulation

Is there a way to adjust all image sizes in a directory?

If I set the max size to 800x600 it will make larger ones smaller and leave smaller ones at their original size.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
for img in *.png; do
    convert "$img" "800x600>" $(basename "$img" .png)_new.png
done
```

`convert` is from ImageMagick. ">" says it's only resized if larger. See [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize) for its other options.

Comment: nice hint about the '>' option!

Comment: `convert` didn't accept the size command for me: convert convert: Unable to open file (800x600>) [No such file or directory].

Comment: I had the same problem, it seemed to think `"800x600>"` was another file.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `-resize` before the resolution parameter.

Answer (score 2):

image magick package needs to be installed:
mogrify -resize 320x240 *.jpg
where 320 = width, 240 = height

or you can just leave width parameter:
mogrify -resize 320 *.jpg
and rest will be taken care of.

Answer (score 2):

Various packages exist for command line or script driven manipulation of image files.

I'd suggest looking at [`netpbm`](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/), or [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  Personally I prefer the former as it's far simpler to use.